# stripe payment - the maximum amount for a single charge is $999,999.99

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway

Is this possible to add amount greater $999,999.99 in stripe payment?
Stripe do not allow me to add amount greater that $999,999.99.

Comment: That's the technical limit imposed by the API. If you have a use case for charging more than that in a single transaction you might want to reach out to Stripe's support in case there is some other option that could work for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot charge more than $999,999.99 in any given single charge.

There is a technical limitation imposed by an eight digit limit on the `amount` value.

> https://stripe.com/docs/currencies#minimum-and-maximum-charge-amounts
>
> The only limit to the maximum amount you can charge a customer is a technical one. The amount value supports up to eight digits (e.g., a value of 99999999 for a USD charge of $999,999.99).

If you have a genuine reason to be transacting that amount of money on a regular basis, then you should be using BACS or similar bank-to-bank clearing service.

Comment: What if the genuine reason is charging in a currency where the minimum denomination is too low? e.g. 999,999.99 COP (minimum wage in colombia) is just about 250USD. For now we're thinking on doing multiple transactions

Comment: @TomasWolf You process payments in USD - so a payment of +999,999.99 COP would need to be converted to it's USD equivalent before sending to Stripe for processing.